# Why do some stars actually produce "Gamma ray bursts"?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, astrophysics, gamma-rays

I looked it up but I haven't found any explanation as to why some stars produce them, I understand that collapsing and merging stars produce them, but my question is why is the energy concentrated in only two beams? what are the mechanics behind that?

Comment: As I understand it (very vaguely, that is) the detail is a mess of non-linear math arising the magnetohydrodynaimcs. How's your math and at what level would you like to be answered?

Comment: @dmckee My math is ok, I can understand calculus and differential equations

Comment: Probably related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68374, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/221890/

Comment: Strictly speaking.... we haven't seen a single gamma ray burster in action closely enough, so we don't really know what the mechanism is. We think that we have a few theoretical mechanisms that may explain these objects and they do, as dmckee points out, all rely on pretty heavy lifting with general relativity and electrodynamics... but the details... that will have to wait for the day when we have much better telescopes.

Comment: A few pulsars gamma-rays modulated with their rotation e.g. Crab Pulsar. Microquasars -binary systems with compact object (black hole neutron star) producing jets. These are analogs to quasars (not really stars). Soft gamma repeaters; highly magnetic slowly  rotating neutron stars. They produce swarms of burst, plus occasional giant flare. Short and long gamma ray bursts. The short gamma-ray bursts are probably from colliding neutron stars. Long gamma-ray bursts collapse of massive star. See abstract of https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rsta.2012.0273

Comment: Two beams originate from symmetry of accretion disk which collimates jets, or in collapsar model massive star collapses faster at poles rather than symetrically.